# How to convert this AngularJS controller in this module to another format?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-controller

I have this AngularJS controller;

```
angular.module('plunker', ['ui.bootstrap']);

var TabsDemoCtrl = function ($scope) {
  $scope.tabs = [
    { title:"Dynamic Title 1", content:"Dynamic content 1" },
    { title:"Dynamic Title 2", content:"Dynamic content 2", disabled: true }
  ];

  $scope.alertMe = function() {
    setTimeout(function() {
      alert("You've selected the alert tab!");
    });
  };

  $scope.navType = 'pills';
};
```

I want to convert it to another controller (from AngularJS seed) to this format below;

```
angular.module('myApp.controllers', []).
  controller('MyCtrl1', [function() {

  }])
  .controller('MyCtrl2', [function() {

  }]);
```

The index.html looks like this;

```
<div ng-controller="TabsDemoCtrl">
  <p>Select a tab by setting active binding to true:</p>
  <p>
    <button class="btn btn-default btn-sm" ng-click="tabs[0].active = true">Select second tab</button>
    <button class="btn btn-default btn-sm" ng-click="tabs[1].active = true">Select third tab</button>
  </p>
  <p>
    <button class="btn btn-default btn-sm" ng-click="tabs[1].disabled = ! tabs[1].disabled">Enable / Disable third tab</button>
  </p>
  <hr />
```

How should the converted controller look like?

I tried the following but it did not work.

```
angular.module('myApp.controllers', []).
  controller('TabsDemoCtrl', [function() {
    $scope.tabs = [
      { title:"Dynamic Title 1", content:"Dynamic content 1" },
      { title:"Dynamic Title 2", content:"Dynamic content 2", disabled: true }
    ];

    $scope.alertMe = function() {
      setTimeout(function() {
        alert("You've selected the alert tab!");
      });
    };

    $scope.navType = 'pills';    
    }])
  .controller('MyCtrl2', [function() {

  }]);
```

What did I do wrong?

Comment: you need to add the function argument $scope :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to inject the `$scope` into the controller to make it work

```
angular.module('myApp.controllers', []).
  controller('TabsDemoCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope) {
    $scope.tabs = [
      { title:"Dynamic Title 1", content:"Dynamic content 1" },
      { title:"Dynamic Title 2", content:"Dynamic content 2", disabled: true }
    ];

    $scope.alertMe = function() {
      setTimeout(function() {
        alert("You've selected the alert tab!");
      });
    };

    $scope.navType = 'pills';    
    }]);
```

Answer (score 0):

You might want to specify $scope in second line. So your code would be like

```
angular.module('myApp.controllers', []).
controller('TabsDemoCtrl', ['$scope', function() {
    $scope.tabs = [
      { title:"Dynamic Title 1", content:"Dynamic content 1" },
      { title:"Dynamic Title 2", content:"Dynamic content 2", disabled: true }
    ];
....
```

Also, make sure your 'myApp.controllers' is registered. That might help.

Comment: 1. when `$scope` is not injected also in the controller function, it will not work... 2. this code registers `myApp.controllers` module, so it doesn't have to be registered before

Comment: ahh, I lost the parameters. Thanks for that and the explanation of myApp.controllers!